# spring amqp async responses and correlate it with a request

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to implement the request-response pattern using spring amqp.
I looked at the docs and examples but i still can't understand how to use **correlation Id** and consume the right response for a request in asynchronous environment.

Assume i have a **Transporter** class which receives a request, sends the request 
to some requestQueue, and then waits(blocking) to a response using a listener to some responseQueue, and then returns the response.

Now, I have an **AsyncSocketService** which listens to requestQueue, and then sends the request via a socket to another server which process the request and returns a response. this server works asynchronously, so if two requests come, the response does not have to be in the same order. That means that the response from **AsyncSocketService** is managed in a different thread that listens to the socket **InputStream**.

After the thread that listen to the socket's **InputStream** receives a response, it publish it to a responseQueue, and then my **Transporter**, who listens to the responseQueue, can return the response to the original caller.

The **Transporter** listens to the responseQueue like this:

```
byte[] response = (byte[]) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(queueName, timeout);
```

But in this way, i can't make sure that a given response is matching the right request.

I've seen some examples to use a reply queue, when you define **SimpleMessageListenerContainer** and **RabbitTemplate** with reply address.
but still i don't understand where the correlation id comes to play and how can i check it. and this solution does not fit for me, because i need my **Transporter** block and wait for a response that match the request.

Important thing to note, the requests and responses have a `refId` field in the byte[] to allow matching between request and response, but i don't want to catch and requeue responses that don't match.

Can someone help find a solution for my use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture is a bit unclear and I'm afraid I can't answer to your question about manual correlation directly, but for the request-reply scenarios there are `RabbitTempalte.sendAndReceive()`. You really can configure it with the fixed `queue` for replies, if that is your requirement:

```
/**
 * The name of the default queue to receive messages from when none is specified explicitly.
 *
 * @param queue the default queue name to use for receive
 */
public void setQueue(String queue) {
```

There is an automatic correlation support which you can control via:

```
/**
 * Set to true to use correlation id provided by the message instead of generating
 * the correlation id for request/reply scenarios. The correlation id must be unique
 * for all in-process requests to avoid cross talk.
 * <p>
 * <b>Users must therefore take create care to ensure uniqueness.</b>
 * @param userCorrelationId true to use user correlation data.
 */
public void setUserCorrelationId(boolean userCorrelationId)
```

At the same time you need to configure this `RabbitTemplate` as a listener to some `MessageListenerContainer` to really consume those async replies.

For true async request/replies there is also an `AsyncRabbitTemplate` variant, which returns `RabbitMessageFuture` for later consumption of the reply.

Anyway it is very important that a `requestQueue` consumer side supports a correlation transferring to the reply back. Otherwise on the producer side there won't be anything to match an async reply with the request has been sent.

All the information is in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#request-reply).

Comment: I'll try to explain the main problem. I have multiple requests that use a socket to write to an old TCP server. For each client socket I have that is connected to this server, I have an handler that read anything coming from it and writing x bytes from it to a queue. The write operation and read operation happen in different context so I can't use `sendAndReceive`. I am trying to use AMQP to coordinate everything but I have to `send` to rabbit in a request thread, in a different thread read from the socket and write to a response queue, and wait in the request thread for the correct response

Comment: Well, it's going to be to hard to implement with the fixed `replyQueue`. You would need to replicate a `PendingReply` logic from the `RabbitTemplate`. How about to consider to rely on the `temporary` anonymous queue per request? This is exactly what is done in the `RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceiveWithTemporary()`. This way you will have a queue per request and no any correlation collision is going to happen. However your consumer has to send replies back using a `replyTo` header from the request, not that fixed `replyQueue`.